# Restoring files with deja-dup fails with "could not restore /home/user/%N"

Tags: deja-dup

Every time I try to restore a file with déja-dup, I'm ending up with the following error:

```
Could not restore /home/username/%N": Could not find file in backup copy
```

And I find a directory %N under my home. What could possibly be wrong? It has this behaviour for every single directory I try to restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turned out to be a simple problem: I used nemo (using nemo-actions) to restore the files which failed.
Using Nautilus, the restoration process works flawlessly.